# List Index for lists that create a grid

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the index of an element in list, obviously I tried the normal list.index() method but its says that the item is not in the list (but it is). Since I'm creating a grid with this list, maybe there is an other method.

Here is the code.

```
grid = [[200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200], [200, 200, 200, 400, 200, 78, 200], [200, 200, 400, 400, 200, 75, 200], [200, 200, 400, 400, 300, 200, 200], [200, 300, 200, 400, 400, 200, 200], [200, 14, 200, 52, 200, 84, 200], [200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200]]

print(grid.index(200))
```

The error is:

ValueError: 200 is not in list

But I can see that grid[0][0] is 200

Hear a photo of the grid created from the list [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwaHa.png)

Comment: With that info, you probably want 2 indexes. One for the inner list and one for the index of the number in the inner list. Then again, there are lots of `200`s in those lists. What is your desired output?

Comment: No list in `grid` is equal to 200, because lists can't be equal to integers.

Comment: I need two index, in this case 200 was an example, my goal is to search in the entire grid a specific number and get it's index in the form grid[][] so that I can change it later in another number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following to get a List of Tuples containing the two co-ordinates in your List of Lists:

```
seeking = 200
idx = [(i,j) for i, x in enumerate(grid) for j, y in enumerate(x) if y == seeking]

print(idx)
```

which produces

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 6), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 4), (2, 6), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 5), (3, 6), (4, 0), (4, 2), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 0), (5, 2), (5, 4), (5, 6), (6, 0), (6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3), (6, 4), (6, 5), (6, 6)]
```

so (0,0) means subList 0, element 0 and so on

Answer (score 1):

Grid is a list of lists. You need to instead index each list inside the "outer" list. For example:

```
for i,l in enumerate(grid):
    if 200 in l:
         print(f"Location: {i,l.index(200)})
```

Comment: it looks like is not working, in this way I'm only getting the index of the row think. I need two index, in this case 200 was an example, my goal is to search in the entire grid a specific number and get it's index in the form grid[][] so that I can change it later in another number.

Comment: @Proton Understood, I modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

You search for an item as cell, but you search in the outter list, rows list